# Custom iq with openfire server

Tags: android, xmpp

I am trying to send this custom IQ to openfire server. but i am not getting any thing in return from server

```
CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<questionrequest  xmlns='profile' from='1' to='10' />");
```

I have installed the required plugin as well. is there something wrong with the server?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same problem, I just restarted my `OPENFIRE` server and it was working fine then. plus check your connection if it remains or disconnects

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<questionrequest  xmlns='profile' from='1' to='10' />");
```

Change it to

```
CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<questionrequest  xmlns='profile' <anytag>from='1' to='10'</anytag> />");
```

Comment: Would you care to explain why you suggest that the constructor of CustomIQ should take a String which is not well-formed XML as argument?

Comment: @user i have solved the problem, the issue was with my query plugin, not with my query syntax, thnks anyways